# Can a pushdown automata have zero final states?

Tags: pushdown-automaton

As per the question, can a pushdown automata have zero final states?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep!  There are many different definitions of PDAs, but usually the definition says that a PDA has a set of accepting states, which must be a subset of the set of all states in the PDA.  The empty set is a valid set, so the PDA doesn't necessarily ever have to accept.  This is how it's possible to build a PDA for the empty language, for example, which is known to be context-free.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Some forms of push-down automaton accept by halting with an empty stack at end of input.  For this form, there is no such thing as a final state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, A PDA can have zero final sates. PDAs that are allowed to have more than one initial state (let's call them PDAI's) are computationally equivalent to conventional PDAs:

Trivially, every conventional PDA can be considered as a PDAI that happens to have one initial state.
Every PDAI can be converted to an equivalent PDA with the process you describe.
So yes, PDAI's accept exactly the context free languages.